# Modificar height funcion

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una consulta SQL que en ocasiones da como resultado 1000 lineas o 10(para modificar el height utilize una funcion con el scrollbar), entonces he creado un filtro pero..al aplicar-lo el height se queda enorme.Me gustaría saber como podría reducir-lo al aplicar el filtro..Alguna idea?

Dejo la funcion que utilizo para hacerlo mas grande, la tabla (resultado de la SQL), la tengo en un iFrame.

```
function calcHeight(iframeElement){
    var the_height=  iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    iframeElement.height=  the_height;

}
```

```html
<div class="filt">
    <div class="titl">
        <p>Direcciones</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contfiltros">
        <div class="tableDirec">
            <form action="CustomerMasterAddressResult.jsp"  method="post"  target="ifrdirecciones">
            <table>  
                <tr>
                    <td width="10px">Ciudad:</td>
                    <td width="10px" ><input type='text' id='tbciudad' name='tbciudad' value='' size='8'></td>
                    <td width="10px">CP:</td>
                    <td  width="10px"><input type='text' id='tbcp' name='tbcp' value='' size='8'></td>
                    <td width="10px">Provincia:</td>
                    <td width="10px"><input type='text' id='tbprovincia' name='tbprovincia' value='' size='8'></td>
                    <td width="10px">Comercial:</td>
                    <td width="10px"><input type='text' id='tbcomercial' name='tbcomercial' value='' size='8'></td>
                    <td width="10px"></a><button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="">Buscar</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
   <br>
</div>
                <div class="iframeCont">
                    <center>
                         <table width="100%" > 
                             <tr>
                                 <td>
                                 <iframe src="CustomerMasterAddressResult.jsp" id="ifrdirecciones" name="ifrdirecciones" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" onLoad="calcHeight(this);" ></iframe>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                         </table>
                     </center>
                </div>
   <%  }

        }

        sql.CloseConnection();
%>



<jsp:include page="/core/ResyntPageClose.jsp"   flush="true"></jsp:include>
```

Ahroa estoy tocando y esta un poco feo , pero el problema lo tengo en el div iFrameCont , en el otro jsp, he escrito la funcion que te dejo aquí , y me devuelve el height correcto despues de aplicar cada filtro el problema (lose por un alert que había puesto), el problema es que no me cambia el height de iFrameCont... y no se que hacer.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
           var alto = document.getElementById('table').offsetHeight;
           document.getElementById('iframeCont'); obj.style.height = alto+"px";

</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir también tu estructura HTML y la hoja de estilos que afecte al iframe en caso de que tengas?

Comment: Intento explicarme lo mejor que puedo...@Hechi

Comment: Si te entiendo bien, utilizas Javascript para redimensionar un iframe al tamaño de su contenido. Y el problema es que a veces es demasiado grande (¿para la pantalla? No me queda claro qué es "demasiado"). ¿Por qué no añades un `if(the_height < XX)` antes de asignarlo? O incluso un `the_height = Math.max(the_height, XX)`.

Comment: Me explico a veces hago una consulta de 1000 lineas y se adapta genial, cuando aplico filtro pasa a 3 lineas...pero el div se queda con el tamaño de las 1000 pero con espacio abajo. @delCano

Comment: Ah, o sea que tu problema es llamar a `calcHeight()` después de cada consulta, ya que por ahora sólo ocurre cuando se carga la página. En tu código no muestras cuando haces ninguna de las dos cosas...

Comment: Exactoo!! Se redimensiona genial pero luego no se "hacerlo pequeño" por así decirlo hahah. @delCano

Comment: ¿`calcHeight` es llamado correctamente cuando cargas nuevo contenido? Puedes verificarlo con un console.log o un alert.

Comment: Ya esta en el onLoad del iFrame por eso mira te dejo un pantallazo de lo que pasa al apliacr filtro, para que se me entienda mejor..@delCano

Comment: Si es llamado cada vez que presiono el boton y actualiza la table , me sale el alert, pero me coje la altura del scroll...@delCano

Comment: Podría hacer un reset del scroll? bff haha @delCano